# APNS - how to disable mobile/apns notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new to APNS.  APNS works well in one ios app I built. I can see notifications are shown when app is in background/closed.

I have two questions:

1. is it possible to group notifications. I would like to group messages based on sender ids. So if someone send 3 messages, only one would be listed in notifications.
2. I need no more system notification can be shown on screen when app is not running.

Can you help?
 thanks

Comment: app is not running then where you want display notification ?

Comment: @mitul marsonia. Question is about APNS. APSN do not get displayed in the app. op: 1) no. 2) You can't do this unless your app sends a message to your server telling it to send no more APNS until further notice

Comment: You could use Silent Push Notification, and let your app decides when it's not in foreground to show them or not.

Comment: If you don't want notifications displayed when the app is in the background, then way are you using APNS at all? If there is content to be obtained from the server, the app could use https to fetch it when the app is active and then post a local notification.

Comment: Hi Potassium, I am using pusher as solution for in-app message. so there is no worry when the app is active.  

APNS is only used when the app is not running/ background currently.   The new requirement there is not to bother user when app is not running, but still need mobile notification when app is in background or stand-by.

My main concern there is that I do not know app status on the server side. I expect apns can help me to decide if show a mobile notification based on app status.  nothing when app is not running, but show it when app is in background.